# nodejs - How to check which portion of code is tested with unit tests?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, code-coverage, istanbul, node.js-tape

I am using `tape` and `istanbul` to write unit tests in my Node.js project and the result is the following:

```
Statements   : 93.04% ( 107/115 )
Branches     : 86.84% ( 33/38 )
Functions    : 90% ( 27/30 )
Lines        : 93.86% ( 107/114 )
```

Is there a way to find out which statements, functions or portion of the code is left untested?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the doc you should find a complete html report under `./coverage` with line by line coverage :

> and this should produce a `coverage.json`, `lcov.info` and `lcov-report/*html` under `./coverage`
>   Sample of code coverage reports produced by this tool (for this tool!): [HTML reports](http://gotwarlost.github.io/istanbul/public/coverage/lcov-report/index.html)

Doc : https://github.com/gotwarlost/istanbul#getting-started

Comment: `istanbul` wasn't generating a .html file in the coverage folder because I was calling the script with `istanbul cover --root ./server --report cobertura ./server/all-tests.js` instead of a `--report html` parameter. Thank you :D